# two css files are conflict

Tags: asp.net, css

My CSS3 Menu Bar is conflicting with the bootstrap.min.css

If I remove the bootstrap css then menu bar looks like below

[image]

Once bootstrap menu is added then it become like below

[image]

Instead of alphabet letters such as Menu1, Menu2, I m using some images on the menu. Because of CSS conflict, menu images comes below the menu border line. I got the image like below (but I want the image should be in center)

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/css3menu1/style.css" />
<link href="Style/vTab/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have linked the both css like above and copied those codes in jsfiddle. I could not find the conflicting part in the CSS. Can anyone please help me.
jsfiddle sample is here...
    https://jsfiddle.net/w3jz075t/

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using icon fonts like fontawesome?

Comment: i didnt know about that icon fonts...let me try that...thank u

Comment: there are many others you can use like glyphicons

Comment: Why don't you use the Bootstrap Navbar? https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at this page. https://getbootstrap.com . I think you're not fully aware of possibilities inside Bootstrap.

Comment: its not an issue with the bootstrap. its just conflict of two css, i would like to know the line that conflict each other

Comment: If you want to find the correct css element then use the Developer Tools inside any browser (preferably Chrome). Here is the video: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/animations/edit-element-name.mp4 . You hit CTRL+SHIT+C and click on the icon where it's not placed correctly and then the rest would be easy to fix. You can make local changes inside that window until you find the correct solution and then you can apply it in your css file.

Comment: @Aruna: I think you can simply solve this issue if you reverse the order of your css file. So add the bootstrap css file above and your style.css file below bootstrap css file and you should not have any issues....let me know.

Comment: @navnit style.css is in master page and the other one in content page

Comment: @Aruna: if you are not able to place the bootstrap file above your style.css file then I guess you need to check that manually like CodeMaster suggested..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reverse the order due to Master page & content page. Finally I have concluded with the issue and identified the conflict code in bootstrap css, its below

```
/*
@media print
{
*
{
text-shadow:none!important;
color:#000!important;
background:transparent!important;
box-shadow:none!important
}

a,a:visited
{
text-decoration:underline
}
a[href]:after
{
content:" (" attr(href) ")"
}
*/
```

really I dont know what they did and how they are root cause for the issue but if I comment those lines then my menu bar places correctly. Thank you all for your support.

Comment: These lines normally only apply to print media, which means they have no effect on your screen render. You should also be carefull what you comment, it seems like you don't include the closure ('}') of the '@media print', it could result in more issues ;)

Answer (score 3):

The order in which you include your CSS files is important, they will load in that order.

If there's 2 lines that impact the same html element, the browser will take the one included last (except if you use the attribute !important).

Comment: thank you! but style.css is in master page and the other one in content page so nothing to change here

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried linking the css files like this:

```
<link href="Style/vTab/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/css3menu1/style.css" />
```

(in reversed order)

so your css styles will apply after the bootstrap ones.
Keep an eye on **!important** after some css properties when troubleshooting with the dev tools!

Good Luck!

Comment: thank you! but style.css is in master page and the other one in content page so nothing to change here

Comment: @Aruna OK (: Glad you've fixed your problem anyways! Have a nice evening!